# Twilio, call forwarding and DTMF during call

Tags: api, twilio, voip, voice, twilio-php

I'm running into a problem with the Twilio-PHP API & the service in general. Here's what I've been trying to accomplish:

1. `TWILIO NUMBER` phone number places outbound call to `CALLER A`.
2. `TWILIO NUMBER` then connects `CALLER A` to their utilities company (`CALLER COMCAST`).
3. Twilio fires off a series of DTMF tones to navigate `CALLER COMCAST`'s long and boring menu sequence on behalf of `CALLER A` (eg. pause 5s, send 2, pause 10s, send 5, pause 4s, send *... so on).
4. `CALLER A` then takes over the call and completes the remainder (eg. talking to a real person, etc.)
5. The call is ended when either side hangs up.

Here's my current code, which doesn't work. I've tried a few different methods, but all fail by means of not being able to play any DTMF tones once the script hits test.xml. It connects `CALLER A` to `CALLER COMCAST` just fine, but nothing happens past that point.

test.php

```
<?php
require_once 'inc/Twilio/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "[sid]";
$token  = "[token]";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls->create(
                        "[CALLER A]",
                        "[TWILIO NUMBER]",
                        array(
                            "method" => "GET",
                            "url" => "[mydomain]/test.xml"
                        )
               );

print($call->sid);
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial EarlyMedia="true" action="[mydomain]/message.xml">
        <Number>
            +[CALLER COMCAST]
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

message.xml

```
<Response>
  <Pause length="10" />
  <Play>[mydomain]/dtmf/1.mp3</Play>
  <Pause length="10" />
  <Play>[mydomain]/dtmf/2.mp3</Play>
  <Pause length="7" />
  <Play>[mydomain]/dtmf/2.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

I'm definitely missing something here but just cannot figure it out. Any help at all would be GREATLY appreciated! <3

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you use the <Play> verbs digits parameter to specify the DTMF you want to send: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#attributes-digits

You can play all of the digits with a single <Play> by specifying 'w' (wait) between the DTMF digits.

Comment: Hey @DevinRader. That gives me the same result. The only reason I'm using MP3 versions is for further troubleshooting. My message.xml never even executes. I'm assuming it's because Twilio's API is waiting for test.xml to finish before launching message.xml. But I don't know how else to get around that?

Comment: Also, should note that using the sendDigits parameter does indeed successfully send DMTF to CALLER COMCAST, however, CALLER A is unable to hear the call audio until sendDigits completes – and there’s a string length limit which makes complex menus and long pauses impossible (too many 500ms pause characters).